# Shorthand for setting variable values

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I am trying to declare 2 variables to the same value ( false ).

I tend to do this all over the place ( like, in almost every object I prototype )

```
var $a= {border:false
,frame:false};
```

or alternately

```
border=false;frame=false;
```

Is there better way I can declare the value of both simultaneously? ( eg a code golf solution )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, if both variables are declared when you set the value. This is kind of quirky, but it works:

```
var frame, 
    border = frame = false;
```

*(this would be the shortest you can get I think)*

Is it better? I don't think so, and you don't really save much. More readable is

```
var frame = false, 
    border = false;
```

Actually there some more combinations you could do, but you cannot do it without repeating either a variable name or the value. E.g. you could also do:

```
var frame = false, 
    border = frame;
```

Of course this only works for **primitive values** (i.e. booleans, (literal) numbers, (literal) strings). If you deal with objects (which includes arrays), then both variables would reference the same object. In this case you really have to initialize them separately:

```
var frame = {}, 
    border = {};

// DON'T DO THIS:
var frame, 
    border = frame = {};
```

---

**Update**, because I feel the need to explain why `var border = frame = false;` does **not** work:

`var` is not transitive here and this expression is actually evaluated from right to left. First, `false` is assigned to `frame`, which will be looked up in the scope chain and in the worst case will become global. Then the value of `frame` is assigned to the local variable `border`.

Comment: Assumeing the shortest version, just out of curiosity, does border become a pointer to frame?

Comment: @Alex: No, primitives are always passed by value. If you have an object, then both would point to the same one. Good point actually.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var border = frame = false;
```

Comment: This will make `frame` global, or at least not define it in the same scope as `border` it it was not declared beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
var border, frame;

border = frame = false;
```